# O que é "o mercado" afinal?

Tags: significado, significado-em-contexto

A palavra **"mercado"** tornou-se jargão do dia-a-dia, na mídia escrita e falada, quando o assunto é política e economia. O significado exato desse uso, no entanto, não parece constar nos dicionários. Tenho ouvido falar em:

- O mau-humor do **mercado** fez o Dólar subir.
- Se as reformas que o **mercado** defende forem feitas, Temer continuará no poder.

> O [**Priberam**](https://www.priberam.pt/dlpo/mercado) cita as seguintes definições para mercado:
>
> 1. Lugar público coberto ou ao ar livre onde se compram mercadorias postas à venda; reunião de comerciantes no mesmo local, para vender.
> 2. Cidade onde se faz o comércio de certos objetos.
> 3. Saída econômica.
> 4. Convenção de compra e venda.
> 5. Qualquer arranjo entre as pessoas, contrato.
> 6. Estado da oferta e da procura.

Já que **"mercado financeiro"** é um termo que se refere às ações e ao local em que se permuta a oferta e a procura de capitais a longo prazo, o **"mercado"**, isoladamente, seria:

- Apenas aqueles indivíduos (pessoa física ou jurídica) que aplicam no mercado financeiro?
- Todos os grandes investidores, independente de aplicarem ou não no mercado financeiro?
- Aqueles que detém grandes fortunas?
- Seria um sinônimo para "o poder financeiro" e, neste caso, englobando todos os indivíduos que possuem capital suficiente para "fazer a diferença" nos rumos da economia, independente de participarem ou não do mercado financeiro?

Comment: Também se fala em "mercado consumidor"...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O "mercado" é um termo um pouco vago mas eu diria que, no final das contas, nesse contexto se resume ao **poder financeiro**.

O significado original provavelmente pode ser bem definido por algo na linha: "Lugar de troca de bens", em que esse `lugar` pode ser abstrato e inclui da feira do agricultor ao pregão da bolsa de valores -- mas, como já claro na pergunta, essa não é a definição mais adequada para os exemplos dados, que não antropomorfizam o mercado, mas sim se referem ao(s) coletivo(s) que o controla(m).

Enquanto *flutuações* (de preços/taxas/etc.) podem ser causadas por investidores em geral, a maior influência é inevitavelmente a dos **grandes detentores e administradores de capital**, mesmo os que não negociam ações: afinal, suas decisões sobre como e quando investir afetam a economia como um todo e, por conseguinte, a bolsa. Um exemplo concreto seriam diretores de grandes empresas.